# Calculus practice problem

Tags: calculus

My teacher assigned each student a practice problem yesterday for the new section we are starting, but I was absent, so I missed his explanation of how to do the problems. Can anyone explain to me how to solve it and provide the answer so I can practice it?

The problem is Suppose that $F(x)=f(\sqrt{1+x^2})$ such that $f'(\sqrt2)=\sqrt2/2$. Compute $F'(1)$.

Comment: Please check that I interpreted everything correctly. Also, did you mean $F'(1)$ at the end?

Comment: What you missed is pretty fundamental. It is called the chain rule: [see here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule).

Comment: Yes, I have to compute F'(1). But I missed the explanation of the "chain rule". I'm notoriously bad at math.

Comment: In addition to the wiki link julien gave, I highly suggest looking at [Khan Academy's videos](https://www.khanacademy.org/) on the chain rule.  They're pretty good, and you should be able to do this problem after watching them.  If you still need help, let us know.

Answer (score 5):

The [*chain rule*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule) states that 
$$
\frac{d}{dx} f(g(x)) = g'(x)f'(g(x)).
$$

Applying this here, we have

$$
F'(x) = [\frac{d}{dx} \sqrt{x^2+1}] [f'(\sqrt{x^2+1})] = \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}} f'(\sqrt{x^2+1}).
$$

Using $x=1$, we have

$$
F'(1) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} f'(\sqrt{2}) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} = \frac{1}{2}.
$$

Comment: You guys are great here! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3):

By the chain rule,
$$
F'(x)=f'(\sqrt{x^2+1})\frac{d}{dx}\sqrt{x^2+1}.
$$
By the chain rule again,
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\sqrt{x^2+1}=\frac{1}{2}(x^2+1)^{-1/2}2x=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}.
$$
So
$$
F'(x)=f'(\sqrt{x^2+1})\cdot\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}.
$$
Now make $x=1$.